# What does this mean from pandas in python: stock['long_entry'] = stock.Close > stock.high

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know stock['long_entry'] is creating a new column and stock.Close and stock.high are existing columns but I don't understand how the 'greater than' is being used here

Comment: This is a signal to enter long position

Answer (score 0):

The boolean from evaluation of stock.Close > stock.high is stored in stock['long_entry']